# How can I implement the loss function of BAD GAN in Keras?

Tags: keras

I want to implement a GAN with complement generator (BAD GAN) for semi-supervised learning. According to this paper
https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.09783
How I can implement the loss function of discriminator and generator of this GAN in Keras?

Answer (score 0):

All Bad GAN functions are implemented in Torch.
If you want to implement them in Keras, you will want to translate the Torch functions to Keras code...

https://github.com/kimiyoung/ssl_bad_gan